# Convert canvas in Symbol Edge Animate

Tags: animation, canvas, adobe-edge

I have a `<canvas>` tag in edge animate. I need to convert this in a symbol to import in other projects, but I don't know how to do that.

This is the tag:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="350" ></canvas>
```

Comment: What does it mean to "convert it to a symbol to import in other projects"?

Comment: I need to convert a canvas tag in a symbol, because i need to call it in a js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you got a file html where store you tag html canvas

```
< canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="350" >
```

In CC animate (abobe) import model (your html file).

Comment: i opened the html document with the tag, but its not enough.
the import dosent have the option import model, i have edge animate cc 2014

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html